# undefined method `_input' for ActiveAdmin after changing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've just changed my model a bit... by doing

`rails g migration remove_XXX_from_YYY XXX:string`

and then

`rails g migration add_AAA_to_YYY AAA:content`

Now I'm trying to go to the active admin page and render the "edit: action.. but I get the error msg:

Showing ..../activeadmin-0.3.2/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb where line #1 raised:

```
undefined method `_input' for #<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0xf859210>


Extracted source (around line #1):

1: render renderer_for(:edit)
```

Application trace:

```
app/admin/posts.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/admin/posts.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I get the same error with "new" action. Except: `1: render renderer_for(:new)`

All other actions with ActiveAdmin work. (show, index, delete).

OBS! I can create and edit posts with the 'normal' _form.html.erb... but not through ActiveAdmin..

Im using ActiveAdmin 0.3.2 and formtastic 1.2.4.

Any suggestions of what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you access the model through the Rails console? Have you tried to reboot the server?

Comment: I've rebooted the server and that doesn't resolve the problem. I can add new posts through the regular views/post/_form.html.erb and the new posts show up. However I can't add new posts through ActiveAdmin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is not Active Admin related, but comes from Formtastic (the gem Active Admin uses for building nice forms). This could be because you are using a custom data-type on one of model attributes.

I would try to override the form inside the ActiveAdmin.register block (either directly or via a partial). I would do so by specifying each attribute manually and then comment out each field one at a time. Each time I would reload the page to see if the error had disappeared. The second the error disappear I know which field is causing the problem. Then I would add `:as => :string` (or whatever other input type was appropriate) to force Formtastic to use that particular input type.

Before example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :birthday
      f.input :foobar
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

After example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :birthday
      f.input :foobar, :as => :string
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

Comment: Just tried. In admin/post.rb.. it just changes the error from `undefined method '_input' for #<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0xf859210>` to `undefined method 'content_input' for #<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0xf859210>` this is the line in admin/post.rb `f.input :vimeo_content, :as => :content` where i've added ", :as => :content"... I think something is wrong on the model side or my migration. Do you maybe think that it will be resolved by trying to redo the migration? (i.e first deleting the column and then adding it..) ty again

Comment: `:content` is not a valid field type. You can see a list of possible input types in the "Available Input Types" section here: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic